# Remarks or Remark?

Tags: grammatical-number

I am confused between these two words. Is *remarks* plural of *remark* ?

My client has a form in his website for capturing enquiries. Client has asked me to put *remarks/remark* field (a multiline textbox) to capture any other thing the visitor wants to tell them.

Now, my question is, how should it be labeled? ***Remarks*** or ***Remark*** ?

Comment: FWIW, the use of "remark" or "remarks" here seems a little odd. I'm not saying it isn't correct, but it just doesn't seem very idiomatic. I think it would be more common to use the word "Comments", and again, although it could be argued that either plural or singluar are acceptable in the context you describe, "Comments" seems the more common approach. Remember the first law of web site design -- people spend the vast majority of their time on other people's web sites, so yours should reflect the patterns and expectations that they learn there.

Comment: *Remarks,* in special usage, is a mass noun, not a plural. Use *Remarks* **with** a final *s.* ODO *Remarks:* " **1** A written or spoken comment: *I decided to ignore his rude remarks* " http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/remark (scroll down to see the entry)

Comment: *Remarks* is the plural of *remark*. Use *Remarks* (or *Comments* or similar) to label a field that lets users record their remarks.

Comment: @Drew See the ODO entry cited above.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, *remarks* is the plural of *remark*.

Now, in the described context, you usually use *remarks*.

Why the plural? Because you want to invite the user to include all remarks he wants to share! If you use the singular, you are basically saying that only one remark is expected / permitted.

A remark could be: "Nice questions." Another remark could be "Question 12 was not relevant to my situation."

Now, presented with a text-box labelled *remark*, I might feel I should chose one of the two remarks, whereas you probably want to have *both*.

So you include *one* text field labelled *remarks*, or you present a variable number of text fields labelled *remark*.

Comment: Wonder if the downvoter would care to explain what is wrong with this answer (or Gary's Student's one for that matter)?